# How to use both jQuery styles and css style sheet?

Tags: jquery, html, css, stylesheet

Is it possible to use both jQuery styles and CSS style sheet?

Currently I have this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
```

I also need to use my cssstylesheet.css as well for custom styling as per the business. How can I achieve this? Does it make sense to add two `<link rel>` tags? One for jQuery styles and the other for custom css sheet.

Comment: Yes, it's common to see multiple stylesheets linked in a single app

Comment: yes you can add multiple `<link rel>` tags

Comment: @ArunPJohny I was just worried that jQuery styles would be *over-written* by the local stylesheet. But then I realized, we can target each id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, add another one with the `href` equal to the file path.

Note that the one added last takes precedent if they're styling the same items.

Comment: Great, I was testing with multiples, but wanted to make sure.